# Passing of MouseEvents to other applications/windows in JavaFX-8

Tags: java, javafx, mouseevent, javafx-8

i was wondering if it is possible to pass an `MouseEvent`, which occurs on a specific `Stage` to pass through the window of another program/application which to be fired there. 
To be more specific, i want to program a HUD-like program for informational purposes, which should not interfere with the normal desktop usage (such as operating scrollbars/buttons which are underneath the "HUD"). 
One approach to accomplish such behaviour could be achieved using the `Robot` class in combination with an MouseListener. 
Example:

```
       scene.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                stage.hide();
                robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK)
                stage.show();
            }
        });
```

That should work (not yet tried), but feels kinda like a workaround, also this attempt should make problems if one tries to handle drag & drop. Are there any other possibilities to pass any kind of `MouseEvents` to other windows? Is it possible to make a `Stage` mouse transparent such as it is possible for `Nodes` ?

Comment: I don't think that there is a clean way to do this (let's hope someone proves me wrong:) ). I guess it is totally OS dependent.